# Websphere 7 - BMP Entity Bean - ejbStore called at end of transaction and not after setter method

Tags: websphere, bmp, ejb-2.x, entity-bean

We are migrating from Weblogic to Websphere 7. It is a legacy application and contains EJB 2.0 beans. The Entity beans have BMP. The session facade beans make updates to the entity beans but the updates are persisted to database (call to ejbStore() methods of entity beans) at the end of the transaction which causes problem as the updates are not visible to other client withing the transaction. In Weblogic there is a setting "delay-updates-until-end-of-tx" which can be set to false. This causes the updates to be persisted without waiting for the end of the transaction. I read that the default behavior of Websphere is to not wait for the end of the transaction but it does not seems to work like that.

I have tried setting the following JVM arguments as well:

-Dcom.ibm.ws.pm.deferredcreate=false
-Dcom.ibm.ws.pm.batch=false

This didn't help either.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dikshit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are declarative options for CMP, but I don't believe there are options for BMPs.  It should be possible to use EJBContextExtension.flushCache() WebSphere Application Server extension method to programmatically force the container to store/flush all outstanding entities:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/fep/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/ejbcontainer/EJBContextExtension.html

Comment: Thanks bkail. This did resolve the issue. I had read and tried setting the deferredOperation attribute to NONE but it did not work. I guess you are right that those work only for CMPs but its not mentioned in the documentation. Thanks again for you help.

Comment: For WebSphere Application Server, the PM (persistence management) component and related terminology is used for EJB 2.x CMP only, so no PM settings will affect BMP.  The EJB container handles those itself.